# Get EntityManager using spring manual transaction management

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

I have PlatformTransactionManager in dependency (JpaTransactionManager actually). I can use TransactionTemplate to perform an action in the transaction. But I can't figure out, how do I retrieve EntityManager to use.

```
@Autowired PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

void doSomething() {
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
            EntityManager entityManager = ???;
            // do work
        }
    });
}
```

Here's related configuration:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() { ... }

@Bean
public FactoryBean<EntityManagerFactory> entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    ...
    return entityManagerFactory;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a class called [EntityManagerFactoryUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryUtils.html) from where you can obtain the current transaction's entity manager based on the [EntityManagerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html) you configured in your [JpaTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html).

For example:

```
JpaTransactionManager tm = context.getBean(JpaTransactionManager.class);
EntityManagerFactory emf = tm.getEntityManagerFactory();

TransactionTemplate template = new TransactionTemplate(tm);
template.execute(status -> {
    EntityManager em = EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(emf);
    Department department = new Department();
    department.setId(15);
    department.setName("Engineering");
    em.persist(department);
    return department;
});
```

Comment: I tried this code inside a function annotated with `@Transactional` and the `EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(emf)` returned `null`. If I try it with `@PersistenceContext` annotation it isn't null, but I'm not sure if it is the correct EntityManager for the transaction.

Comment: The original question is about manual transaction management. If your method is marked as `@Transactional` then you're not using manual transactions and there is no point in using this answer.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Can you guide how to get entityManager reference inside Transactional method. i.e from current active Transaction. As I want to inject entity manager from current transaction to Hibernate Search's FulTextEntityManager.

Answer (score 3):

You can inject it with:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented my own simple transaction template:

```
@Component
public class JpaTransactionTemplate {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public void execute(Consumer<EntityManager> consumer) {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        try {
            EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            try {
                consumer.accept(entityManager);
                transaction.commit();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                try {
                    transaction.rollback();
                } catch (Exception rollbackException) {
                    e.addSuppressed(rollbackException);
                }
                throw e;
            }
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }
}
```